# FireDAC could not handle parameter names longer than 30 chars

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, firedac

I use Oracle database version 19.3.0 and it can handle parameter names longer than 30 chars. If I execute in Delphi FireDAC-procedure "ExecProc" to call Stored Procedure in SQL, Delphi throws "ORA-01036 : illegal Variable name/number" exception and calling of the procedure terminates prematurely, because one parameter name is longer then 30 chars.
Is there some FireDAC property to change this behavior without changing parameters name length?

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\data\firedac\FireDAC.Phys.Oracle.pas"
[image: FireDAC.Phys.Oracle]

Comment: `ORA-01036 : illegal Variable name/number` comes from Oracle not Delphi. Often from trying to do DDL without using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: Do you know what the 'compatible' parameter of Oracle is set to?

Comment: Run *select * from database_compatible_level;* If the resulting level is 12.2 or higher then your database supports variable names of 128 bytes. Unfortunately many DBAs were/are reluctant to set that (despite the default). Note: That is not as far back as it would seem. Oracle changed the way it assigns version numbers and went from 12x directly to 18x.

Comment: There is no problem with compatible level, compatible=19.0.0. I found in FireDAC.Phys.Oracle unit an if-statement, where parameter name length is shorten if length is > 30 characters (See above). I can't understand why FireDAC does not use 128 characters.

Comment: That code is still in 10.4.2. Looks like Firedac has not been updated to fully support longer names which as already mentioned came with Oracle 12.2 (around 2017/2018 time frame).

Comment: I have contacted Embarcadero Support and they suggested a solution. I should change ParamBindMode from pbByName to pbByNumber and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Change pbByName to pbByNumber

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); begin
FDStoredProc1.ParamBindMode := pbByNumber;
FDStoredProc1.FetchOptions.Items := [fiBlobs, fiDetails]; //This disables automatic fetching of parameters from server
FDStoredProc1.Params.CreateParam(ftString,'Averylongparamternamethathopefullyislongerthanthirtycharacters',ptInput);
FDStoredProc1.params.CreateParam(ftString,'outparam',ptOutput);
FDStoredProc1.Params[0].AsString := 'Hello World';  

FDStoredProc1.ExecProc; 

ShowMessage(FDStoredProc1.Params[1].AsString);
end;
```

Comment: Better to use a code block instead of an image.

Comment: Ok , I have changed :) Thanks